# Undefined symbols with extern templates in a static library

Tags: c++, templates, extern, c++14

As far as I know the new extern template functionality exists to speed up compile and link times. I am trying to use this in a (static) library, which as far as I know should work, since [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#extern-templates) explicitly mentions libraries.

What I have is a header file containing something along the lines of

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
  // Definitions of the methods
};

extern template class Foo<int>;
```

And an implementation file

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
template class Foo<int>;
```

These are used to build a static library `libfoo`, which is then linked to the corresponding unit test `FooTest`. The linking then gives me undefined symbol errors for every method called on Foo objects in the test.

What am I doing/getting wrong here?

Comment: How are you linking to the library? Link order matters, ensure your `-l` option comes after the files that depend on it.

Comment: I'm using CMake, but linking by hand and putting the library as the last argument does not change anything. My command was `clang++ -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -I../../include -L. -DCATCH_CONFIG_MAIN ../../test/FooTest.cpp libfood.a`, and with `-l` in front of `libfood.a` (CMake's is a little more complex, but basically doing the same).

Comment: (Unlikely to be the cause of the problem but that should be `-lfood` not `-llibfood.a`)

Comment: I am sorry, I mistyped. I tried `-lfood` and `libfood.a` at the end.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, using clang or GCC, so you must be doing something that you've not shown in the question. Please update the question with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem (you should be able to produce a reduced FooTest.cpp that is only a few lines long, without using Catch, and add one or two member functions to `Foo` to demonstrate the problem). Include the compilation and linking commands, and the full errors.

Comment: [OK, here you go](https://github.com/koljakube/so-27425943-extern-template). I'm not sure this has something to do specifically with extern template, but it only appeared after I introduced them. All missing symbols point to `constexpr` methods or constructors in my real project. Changing the order of the method definitions reduces the number of problems, but I'm not sure yet if there is a combination that cleanly links. And I would prefer to order my methods by task, not by some weird linker quirk. Putting the method definitions outside the class didn't help by the way.

Comment: Hm, OK. I'm on `Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)`, which, based on the absence of a `-std=c++14` option, is at least not equal to clang 3.5. I guess I will have to manually install a second version of clang, which had not done yet to avoid causing conflicts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your github code I can reproduce it with GCC 5.0 or Clang 3.4 but not Clang 3.6 (built from svn).

When it fails `Foo.cpp.o` does not contain a definition of `qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo(int const&)`

```
$ nm -C Foo.cpp.o 
                 U qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo(int const&)
0000000000000000 W qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo()
                 U qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo(int const&)
0000000000000000 W qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo()
0000000000000000 W qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::operator[](unsigned long) const
0000000000000000 W std::array<int, 2ul>::operator[](unsigned long) const
0000000000000000 W std::__array_traits<int, 2ul>::_S_ref(int const (&) [2], unsigned long)
```

But using Clang 3.6 that symbol is defined in

```
$ nm -C Foo.cpp.o 
0000000000000000 W qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo(int const&)
0000000000000000 W qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo()
0000000000000000 W qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo(int const&)
0000000000000000 W qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo()
0000000000000000 n qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo(int const&)
0000000000000000 n qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::Foo()
0000000000000000 W qux::Foo<int, 2ul>::operator[](unsigned long) const
0000000000000000 W std::array<int, 2ul>::operator[](unsigned long) const
0000000000000000 W std::__array_traits<int, 2ul>::_S_ref(int const (&) [2], unsigned long)
0000000000000000 W std::array<int, 2ul>::end()
0000000000000000 W std::array<int, 2ul>::data()
0000000000000000 W std::array<int, 2ul>::begin()
0000000000000000 W int* std::__addressof<int>(int&)
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, it might be a bug in Clang which has now been fixed, but it's strange that GCC has the same bug.

The function that causes the problem uses C++14's relaxed constexpr rules (looping in a constexpr function), so I assume it's a bug in the compilers' implementation of that new feature.

Comment: Interesting. You wouldn't happen to have tested this with Clang 3.5 (current stable version) as well, did you? I'd prefer to avoid build both 3.5 and HEAD as it takes ages on my machine. Update: Lucky me finding that edge case. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: No, I don't have a build of 3.5 sitting around, sorry.

Comment: OK, tried again with clang++-3.5 (latest version available via homebrew), and the bug seems to be fixed there. Now I get clang assertion failures during build, but these are unrelated to the question here. Thanks again for helping me diagnose the problem!